# Convert JSON back to Data in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

I have the following Haskell to call my WCF Service:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import GHC.Generics
import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens

data Point = Point { x :: Int, y :: Int } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance ToJSON Point
instance FromJSON Point

data Rectangle = Rectangle { width :: Int, height :: Int, point :: Point } deriving (Generic, Show)
instance ToJSON Rectangle
instance FromJSON Rectangle

main = do        
    let p = Point 1 2
    let r = Rectangle 10 20 p 
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/Rectangle"   
    let opts = defaults & header "Content-Type" .~ ["application/json"]
    r <- postWith opts url (encode r)    
    let returnData = r ^? responseBody
    case (decode returnData) of
        Nothing       -> BS.putStrLn "Error decoding JSON"
        Just json     -> BS.putStrLn $ show $ decode json
```

The output in this case is:

```
Just "{\"height\":20,\"point\":{\"x\":1,\"y\":2},\"width\":10}"
```

I already tried it with fromJSON:

```
print $ fromJSON returnData
```

and got this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Value'
                with actual type `Maybe
                                    bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
    In the first argument of `fromJSON', namely `returnData'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `fromJSON returnData'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My question is now how to convert this JSON string back to an object of type "Rectangle"?

**EDIT 1:** I changed my code due to Janos Potecki's answer and get now the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `ByteString'
    Expected type: ByteString
      Actual type: String
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `show $ decode json'
    In the expression: BS.putStrLn $ show $ decode json
    In a case alternative:
        Just json -> BS.putStrLn $ show $ decode json
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

**EDIT 2:** i changed it to:

```
main = do        
    let point = Point 1 2
    let rectangle = Rectangle 10 20 point
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/Rectangle/Move/100,200"   
    let opts = defaults & header "Content-Type" .~ ["application/json"]
    r <- postWith opts url (encode rectangle)    
    let returnData = (r ^? responseBody) >>= decode
    case returnData of
     Nothing       -> BS.putStrLn "Error decoding JSON"
     Just json     -> BS.putStrLn json
```

and now i get:

```
No instance for (FromJSON ByteString)
      arising from a use of `decode'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `decode'
    In the expression: (r ^? responseBody) >>= decode
    In an equation for `returnData':
        returnData = (r ^? responseBody) >>= decode
```

Comment: The `fromJSON` function does not parse JSON, it just converts parsed JSON into some other Haskell data structure. You want `decode` instead. However, `returnData` is not a `ByteString`, it is a `Maybe ByteString`, so you will have to pattern match, use `>>=`, or some other tool to handle the possibility of `returnData` being `Nothing`. In this example, `print (decode =<< returnData)` should do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working solution

```
r' <- asJSON =<< postWith opts url (encode rectangle) :: IO Res
case r' of
     Nothing        -> print "Error decoding JSON"
     Just x         -> print x
```

For performance I'd suggest you add the following to your `instance ToJSON`:

```
instance ToJSON Point where
       toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions
```

and the same for `Rectangle`

Comment: I tried your solution and now i'm getting another error, please see my Edit 1 above

Comment: i changed it and get now: `Couldn't match expected type `ByteString'
                with actual type `Maybe ByteString'
    In the first argument of `decode', namely `returnData'
    In the expression: (decode returnData)`

Comment: oh, that means that returnData is of type `Maybe`

Comment: That means that `r ^? responseBody` returns something of type maybe hence you can combine those with `>>=`

Comment: i changed it and now i get: No instance for (FromJSON ByteString)
      arising from a use of `decode'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `decode'
    In the expression: (r ^? responseBody) >>= decode
    In an equation for `returnData':
        returnData = (r ^? responseBody) >>= decode

Comment: wait, why are you doing `r <- ...` ??? You have already bound `r` in `let r = Rectangle...`
Change `r` into `r'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118633/discussion-between-janos-potecki-and-manzmoody).